# WP7: How to override static resources?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, resources, overriding

How do I override static resources in Windows Phone 7 Apps?

I am stacking many TextBoxes in a list and I want to make the margin between them smaller, but without retemplating the entire control.

I figured PhoneTouchTargetOverhang is whats causing the large margin. How do I override it?

I have tried adding this to my PhoneApplicationPage.Resources:

```
<Thickness x:Key="PhoneTouchTargetOverhang">0</Thickness>
```

... but it is not affecting anything.

Also I'm trying to override other resources such as default background and foreground colors without success. Whatever I do, nothing happens.

Clarification:

- I don't want to re-template the entire control, only change some resources used by the template.
- I don't care if its "bad design" to remove the touch margins on the textbox-template. For the case I'm working on its a requirement to have them close together...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this out but setting the `Top` and `Bottom` margins to negative numbers should move the `TextBox`es closer together.

```
<TextBox Margin="0,-10,0,-10" Text="Some text"/>
```

Comment: This causes textboxes to overlap and pressing one textbox could enter edit mode on another textbox.

Comment: Try starting with -1 instead of -10 and changing the margins until they are to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood...

But if you're just repeating the TextBoxes inside a databound ListBox then you I think could just set the Margin for these TextBoxes inside the DataTemplate.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{...}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox Margin="0" Text="{...}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: No, setting Margin to 0 is not working. Whats causing the margin in the TextBox-template is the PhoneTouchTargetOverhang-resource. If I only could override it somehow...

Comment: Thank for the explanation. Just had a play within VS2010 - I'm not convinced that PhoneTouchTargetOverhang is what you need to change - but it does looks like you're going to need to restyle the TextBox in Blend.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out these resources when trying to change static resources:

[How to: Apply Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

and also

[Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) - This actually shows how to style a textbox in xaml (in your case the textbox control). Since your working in wp7 you can declare these in the app.xaml file. This is a nice approach if you wish to apply these styles throughout the app. If not Praetorian's solution is an alternative for specific controls you would like to style.

From what I've used there is no reason why this shouldn't work. And honestly in my opinion it's better (neater) to create a template than start applying negative margins on individual controls in your xaml files.

Be aware also that there is a reason for the margins for user experience purposes. Put them too close and it makes it difficult to select a certain control. I believe there is a requirement for in the [design guidelines](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/18/windows-phone-7-series-ui-design-amp-interaction-guide.aspx) but I'm not sure exactly.

Here is an example of what to put in app.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">  
    <Setter Property="Template">  
         <Setter.Value> 
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
              </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[Here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63388/388566.aspx) is full example on creating a template for the textbox control, if you don't want to start from scratch.

HTH.

Comment: Can't find info about how to override static resources on the links you provided... I don't want to restyle/retemplate completely, only change one or two resources used by the template. Has this ever been possible in WP7 and removed? I don't get it.

Comment: @Andreas from what I know the only way to override a static resource is to define a new one in the App.xaml or modify the tag directly. Also remember you don't have to define a completely "new" template just apply styles you need. check the second link again. I think you can define a specific style (for example a margin) without having to define an entire template for a control.